# Sencha Touch 2.2.1 not working correctly in Chrome and Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, sencha-touch-2.2

I have an application, written in Sencha Touch 2.2.1, we just saw that on current Chrome (43) and on Android 4.x and 5.x some parts of the application aren't working, while on Safari on Windows, Mac and iOS everything is fine.

e.g. we have the following Code on the index.html getting called:

```
Ext.Viewport.items.get('main').setActiveItem(target);
```

Where `target`is the name of the view to be loaded.

In the view we have the following code, that is not called in Chrome:

```
...
listeners: {
  painted: function () {
    this.fireEvent('isPainted');
  }
},
...
```

The template of the view gets rendered to the html, but the listener is never called.

Any ideas on how this can be handled?